# how to use URL_ALIAS for search result of apachesolr module?

Tags: uri, search

I am using apachesolr in drupal 6.22 module to search. the links of the results look like http://mywebsite.com/node/NID , how can i manage it to show the url alias instead of displaying node/NID representation.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am running the same configuration as you and this has the SEF urls by default.

Have you checked your URL Aliases? Does this problem occur for ALL nodes in SERPS? I would try rebuilding your aliases

Comment: it seems some of nodes don't have url alias... i think it is my mistake :)